# Заполнение recyclerview данными из MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, json, recyclerview

Из сервера приходят json ответы из БД MySQL. Как заполнить recyclerview полученными данными? При этом, при выборе элемента списка должен быть получен id записи в БД.
Сразу скажу, новичок в этом деле, о парсинге json знания небольшие.

Answer (score 1):

1 Создаете модель данных `PoJO` на основе ответа сервера.

2 Подключаете библиотеку `Retrofit` и смотрите на сайте как с ней работать. Там , к счастью все просто.

3 Делаете запрос, к вам в Колбэке приходит ответ в виде списка `ArrayList`

4 Этот список засовываете в адаптер `RecyclerView`